# Count the number of times a character occurs in a text file

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and I want to count the number of times a character occurs in a text file. The user inputs the path to the text file and the char to search for. The program currently doesn't find any characters. What am I doing wrong? This is the code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName;

        fileName = readInput("Please enter the path to the file: ");
        StreamReader fromFile = new StreamReader(fileName);
        string line;

        while ((line = fromFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        int count = 0;
        char search;
        search = readSearch("Please enter the character you want to search for: ");

        while ((line = fromFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            foreach (char letter in line)
            {
                if (search == letter)
                {
                    count ++;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0} was found {1} time(s).", search, count);
        Console.ReadLine();
        fromFile.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string readInput(string questionPath)
    {
        Console.Write(questionPath);
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        return input;
    }

    private static char readSearch(string questionSearch)
    {
        Console.Write(questionSearch);
        char input = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
        return input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're writing the file to the screen before counting the chars that match.  In doing so, you move the `StreamReader` to the end of the file, and don't reset it.  Reset your reader each time (and use `using`):

```
StreamReader fromFile;
using(fromFile = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
     string line;
     while ((line = fromFile.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(line);
     }
}

int count = 0;
char search;
search = readSearch("Please enter the character you want to search for: ");

using(fromFile = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
     while ((line = fromFile.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
        //....
     }
}
```

Or you could read the file into memory initially.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have already read through the entire stream. A simple fix is to restart the read from the start. This can be done by performing the following before you starting your count operation:

```
        fromFile.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

As an additionally bit of information, you can replace your count operation with a LINQ statement. Replace the:

```
            foreach (char letter in line)
            {
                if (search == letter)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
```

with:

```
            count += line.Count(letter => search == letter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will open a file and count how many of each character is in it, and output the totals to another file.

```
            if (File.Exists(charCountFileName)) File.Delete(charCountFileName);

            SortedDictionary<ushort, int> charsDict = new SortedDictionary<ushort, int>();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(inputFileName))
            {
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = r.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
                    {
                        if (!charsDict.ContainsKey((ushort)buffer[i]))
                        {
                            charsDict.Add((ushort)buffer[i], 1);
                        }
                        else
                            charsDict[(ushort)buffer[i]]++;
                    }

                }
            }           

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(charCountFileName, FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
                foreach (var entry in charsDict)
                    file.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", entry.Key, Convert.ToChar(entry.Key), entry.Value);
```